# Flash Able Dashboard

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have flash able dashboard system CRM. I want to implement Facebook Live chat (Just Like customer Support)
So I want to that the facebook live chat can be access from the Flash Able CRM directly to chat with customers.
Does Facebook have live chat Api to be used in our CRM or any application

Can anyone help me in this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccYUz.png)
Here is the image where i want to implement facebook live chat and i can chat to my customers from this flash able Admin dashboard

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform

Answer (score 0):

you need to read the official documentation : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/facebook-chat-plugin/

```
    <!-- Messenger Chat Plugin Code --> <div id="fb-root"></div> <div id="fb-customer-chat" class="fb-customerchat"></div>
    <script> 
    var chatbox = document.getElementById('fb-customer-chat');
    chatbox.setAttribute("page_id", "PAGE-ID");
 chatbox.setAttribute("attribution", "biz_inbox");
 </script>
 <script>
 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
 FB.init({ xfbml : true, version : 'API-VERSION' });
 };
 (function(d, s, id) { 
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) return; 
 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; 
 js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk')); 
 </script>
```